# How to clear queue of MPMusicPlayerController and add new queue when Song finished according to requirement

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmusicplayercontroller

After every song is finished I'm clearing the queue and then adding a new queue. However, the notification (playing/paused/stopped/playing/paused/playing/paused/paused) is called multiple times. It eventually stops the audio within the app and starts playing from iTunes.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
-(void)clearqueueAndAddNewQueue
{
    NSMutableArray *allTheSongs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    NSLog(@"setupMusic:");
    for (SongsList *obj_songsList in arrSongs) {

        //  NSLog(@"mediaTitle: %@",obj_songsList.mediaTitle);
        MPMediaQuery *songQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
        [songQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:obj_songsList.persistentId forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID]];
        NSArray *songs = [songQuery items];
        [allTheSongs addObjectsFromArray: songs];
    }

    //Rearrange Array in Random Objects
    NSUInteger count = [allTheSongs count];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Select a random element between i and end of array to swap with.
        NSInteger nElements = count - i;
        NSInteger n = (arc4random() % nElements) + i;
        [allTheSongs exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:n];
    }

    //Modify Queue
    if ([[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {

        MPMusicPlayerController *musicplayercontroller = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
        MPMediaItemCollection *currentQueue = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:allTheSongs];
        MPMediaItem *nowPlaying = [[currentQueue items] objectAtIndex:0];
        [musicplayercontroller setQueueWithItemCollection:currentQueue];
        [musicplayercontroller setNowPlayingItem:nowPlaying];
        [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl = musicplayercontroller;
    }

    //I have also used this instead of above mentioed Modify Queue
    if ([[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
        MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate =
        [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: @"Non_Existant_Song_Name"
                                         forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        MPMediaQuery *q = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
        [q addFilterPredicate: predicate];
        [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl setQueueWithQuery:q];
        [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl.nowPlayingItem = nil;
        [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl stop];



        MPMediaItemCollection *currentQueue = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:allTheSongs];
        [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl setQueueWithItemCollection:currentQueue];
        [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl play];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use This Method it will help to clear queue and create or add new queue without any issue.

```
- (void)setupMusic:(NSArray *)arrSongs forTaggedValue:(NSString *)taggedValue {

    NSMutableArray *allTheSongs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    NSLog(@"setupMusic:");
    for (SongsList *obj_songsList in arrSongs) {

        //  NSLog(@"mediaTitle: %@",obj_songsList.mediaTitle);
        MPMediaQuery *songQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
        [songQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:obj_songsList.persistentId forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID]];
        NSArray *songs = [songQuery items];
        [allTheSongs addObjectsFromArray: songs];
    }

    //Modify Queue
    if ([[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {

        [self removeNotificationCenterForMusicPlayerController];
         MPMediaPropertyPredicate *predicate =
         [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: @"Non_Existant_Song_Name"
         forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
         MPMediaQuery *q = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
         [q addFilterPredicate: predicate];
         [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl setQueueWithQuery:q];
         [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl.nowPlayingItem = nil;
         [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl stop];

        MPMediaItemCollection *currentQueue = [[MPMediaItemCollection alloc] initWithItems:allTheSongs];
        [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl setQueueWithItemCollection:currentQueue];
        [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl setRepeatMode:MPMusicRepeatModeAll];
        [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl play];

        [self addNotificationCenterForMusicPlayerController];
        [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
    }
}
```

And Also use this code, which is helpful to work your [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl (MPMusicPlayerContoller's object) and prevents to go to Itunes.

```
#pragma mark - For Hadle the Active Bugs Of MPMusicPlayerController
- (BOOL)isPlaybackStateBugActive {
    MPMusicPlaybackState playbackState = [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl.playbackState;
    if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
        AudioSessionInitialize (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound;
        AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof (sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);
        AudioSessionSetActive (true);

        UInt32 audioIsPlaying;
        UInt32 size = sizeof(audioIsPlaying);
        AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, &size, &audioIsPlaying);

        if (!audioIsPlaying){
            NSLog(@"PlaybackState bug is active");
            [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl pause];
            [btnPlayOrPause setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:KPlayImage] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

addNotificationCenterForMusicPlayerController Method

```
#pragma mark - Default NotificationCenter For iPodLibrary/MusicPlayerController
- (void)addNotificationCenterForMusicPlayerController {

    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [notificationCenter addObserver: self selector: @selector (handle_NowPlayingItemChanged:) name: MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification object: [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl];

    [notificationCenter addObserver: self selector: @selector (handle_PlaybackStateChanged:) name: MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object: [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl];



   // [notificationCenter addObserver: self selector: @selector (handle_VolumeChanged:) name: MPMusicPlayerControllerVolumeDidChangeNotification object: [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl];

   // [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
}
```

removeNotificationCenterForMusicPlayerController Method

```
- (void)removeNotificationCenterForMusicPlayerController {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification object: [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object: [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl];

   // [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMusicPlayerControllerVolumeDidChangeNotification object: [AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl];

    [[AppDelegate appDel].musicPlayerCtrl endGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];
}
```